# Why is Int a subtype of Comparable<Int> in Kotlin but HashMap is not a subtype of Comparable<HashMap>

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am reading through the [Kotlin Doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints) and found this claim that I do not understand. Might someone be able to explain?

Given

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> sort(list: List<T>) {  ... }
```

then

```
sort(listOf(1, 2, 3)) // OK. Int is a subtype of Comparable<Int>
sort(listOf(HashMap<Int, String>())) // Error: HashMap<Int, String> is not a subtype of Comparable<HashMap<Int, String>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `kotlin.Int` implements `kotlin.Comparable<Int>` so the upper bound of the type `T` in the function `sort` is satisfied since the list of `T` is a list of `Int`.

Instead, `HashMap<K, V>` doesn't implement `Comparable<HashMap<K, V>>` so the upper bound of the type `T` in the function `sort` is not satisfied since the list of `T` is a list of `HashMap<Int, String>`.

To make it `Comparable`, you can create your custom `HashMap` which is also `Comparable`:

```kotlin
class ComparableHashMap<K, V>: HashMap<K, V>(), Comparable<HashMap<K, V>> {
    override fun compareTo(other: HashMap<K, V>): Int {
        // Implement comparison.
    }
}
```

Comment: hahaha, I guess I should have just opened an IDE and look up both Int and HashMap. (I thought the claim some entirely based on what was presented, without taking into account further context.) Thanks!